# randomly sample a vector-ARMA model

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, arima, autoregressive-models

I intend to randomly sample a VARMA model but I cannot seem to see a function in statsmodels for this, I studied the example on the ARMA and can replicate this successfully for a 1 variable.

```
# for the ARMA
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA 
import statsmodels.api as sm


arparams=np.array([.9,-.7])
maparams=np.array([.5,.8])
ar=np.r_[1,-arparams]
ma=np.r_[1,maparams]
obs=10000
sigma=1

# for the VARMA
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax import VARMAX 

# generate a a 2-D correlated normal series
mean = [0,0]
cov = [[1,0.9],[0.9,1]]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,100)

# fit the data into a VARMA model
model = VARMAX(data, order=(1,1)).fit()
`enter code here`
# I cant seem to find a way to randomly sample the VARMA
```

Answer (score 1):

Results objects from fitting a VARMAX model have a `simulate` method which can be used to generate a random sample. For example:

```
mod = VARMAX(data, order=(1,1))
res = mod.fit()

# to generate a time series of length 100 following the VARMAX process described by `res`:
sample = res.simulate(100)
```

This is true of any state space model, including `SARIMAX`, `UnobservedComponents`, `VARMAX`, and `DynamicFactor`.

(Also, the model class has a `simulate` method. The main difference is that since model objects don't have associated parameter values, you need to pass a particular parameter vector in that case).